# remove keyboard control on flash slider component

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-v3-components

by default the flash slider component can be manipulated with the keyboard. Is there a way to disable this behavior so that users can only drag the slider component with their mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just set the 'focusEnabled' public property of the 'Slider' object to false:

```
import fl.controls.Slider;

var slider:Slider = new Slider();
addChild(slider);

slider.focusEnabled = false;
```

This will indicate that the 'Slider' object can't recieve focus after the user clicks on it and therefore not allow the keyboard to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Taurayi and @Grant mentioned, changing focus would be the simples.

Here's a dirtier way of doing somewhat the same:

```
slider.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus);
function onFocus(event:FocusEvent):void {
    stage.focus = null;
}
```

Although `slider.focusEnabled = false;` is much simpler.

Here's an even dirtier way:

```
import flash.sampler.getMemberNames;

removeKeyboardListeners(slider);

function removeKeyboardListeners(dispatcher:EventDispatcher):void{
    var members:Object=getMemberNames(dispatcher);
    for each (var name:QName in members) {
        if (name.localName=="listeners") {
            var numListeners:int = dispatcher[name].length;
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < numListeners ; i++){
                try{
                    try{
                        if(dispatcher[name][i]){
                            dispatcher.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,dispatcher[name][i]);
                            dispatcher.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,dispatcher[name][i]);
                        }
                    }catch(e:Error){trace(e.message);}
                }catch(e:ReferenceError){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want a lengthy, but less dirty way, simply subclass fl.controls.Slider and set that as the class for the Slider symbol in your library. In your subclass you would add:

```
override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {}
```

keyDownHandler is inherited from fl.core.UIComponent and in Slider.as it handles the keyboard updates.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
 stage.focus = stage;
```

To the SliderEvent.CHANGE handler

This will shift focus to the stage, and therefore disable keyboard activity on the slider.